# How to receive a custom data type from socket read?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost

I want to receive a data (of a custom type say CMYType)
I have the following code;

```
using namespace boost::asio;

streambuf receivedStreamBuffer;
streambuf::mutable_buffers_type bufs;
bufs = receivedStreamBuffer.prepare( sizeof(CMYType) );
std::size_t length = read( *m_pReciver->ConSocket(), 
                           buffer(bufs, sizeof(CMYType)),  
                           transfer_all(),
                           ec);
```

Any idea on how to convert receivedStreamBuffer to an object of type CMYType?!

Comment: have you ever thought to serialize CMYType first ? Or are you sure it's trivial and standard layout (aka POD) so that it can be transfered in binary form without risk ? And in the latter case, are you sure both side of the socket are using the same endianness and floating point encoding ?

Comment: 1) I am new to tcp/ip programming. so I am not sure about serializing the data packets 2) I am sure both sides as using same datatype. can someone help me to figure out how to get the useful data and assign it to an object CMYType?!

Comment: You may want to get a copy of "Effective TCP/IP programming". It is a good book and covers the basics. Most of the time you want to exchange some form of message between applications. I would recommend to take a look at some higher-level library for doing this. I prefer zeroMQ for this, and would recommend to read the excellent guide:http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all.

Answer (score 1):

Your code "could" actually work. However, as [Christophe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3723423/christophe) pointed out, there are a number of issues you need to consider.

**TCP/IP Programming**

In your comment you mention that you are new to TCP/IP programming. I would suggest you read through ["Beej's guide to network programming"](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/). It's a short (about 20 pages) and decent introduction that covers nearly all aspects of network programming, including the ones below. It's well worth the time and it's free.

**Endianness**

This is general basic problem of network communication. You absolutely **need** to deal with it if you don't have control on what machine your software runs. Or if you want portable code. You *may skip this* only if you are absolutely sure that both (all) of the machines that communicate are of the same architecture.

If you need to understand more of the problem, [these](http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/) [three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) [websites](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/endian.html) are good starting points.

**Serialization**

Serialization is both, a generalization of the problem and a "silver bullet" that can solve the above problems (if applied correctly). The basic idea is to convert your datatypes (structs) into a "serial stream" which can be transported over any channel (network) and converted back into your type. Boost has a [serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) that can be used for this.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind portability and ABI caveats mentioned by others.

If, as you say in a comment, you're sure your client and server are compatible in these ways:

### For POD data

Provided your type satisfies the POD requirements, you can use `buffer_cast`:

In fact you can have it implicit using the `buffer` function:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd3a726367ad78a2)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

struct CMYType {
    float a,b,c;
};

static_assert(std::is_pod<CMYType>::value, "Not bitwise serializable");

static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, CMYType const& cmy) {
    return os << "[" << cmy.a << "," << cmy.b << "," << cmy.c << "]";
}

static boost::mutex mx;

void server() {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    using namespace boost::asio;

    io_service svc;
    ip::tcp::acceptor acc(svc, ip::tcp::endpoint{ {}, 6767 });

    {
        ip::tcp::socket sock(svc);
        acc.accept(sock, ec);

        CMYType data;
        std::size_t length = read(sock, buffer(&data, sizeof(data)), ec);
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lk(mx);
        std::cout << "length:" << length << " data: " << data << "\n";
    }

    {
        ip::tcp::socket sock(svc);
        acc.accept(sock, ec);

        std::vector<CMYType> data(10);
        std::size_t length = read(sock, buffer(data), ec);

        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lk(mx);
        std::cout << "length:" << length << " data: { ";

        for(auto& cmy : data)
            std::cout << cmy << ", ";

        std::cout << " }\n";
    }
}

void client() {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    using namespace boost::asio;

    io_service svc;

    {
        ip::tcp::socket sock(svc);
        sock.connect({ {}, 6767 }, ec);

        CMYType data { 1, 2, 3 };

        std::size_t length = write(sock, buffer(&data, sizeof(data)), ec);
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lk(mx);
        std::cout << "sent: " << length << " bytes\n";
    }

    {
        ip::tcp::socket sock(svc);
        sock.connect({ {}, 6767 }, ec);

        std::vector<CMYType> data { 
            { 1,  2,  3  }, { 4,  5,  6  }, { 7,  8,  9  }, { 10, 11, 12 }, { 13, 14, 15 },
            { 16, 17, 18 }, { 19, 20, 21 }, { 22, 23, 24 }, { 25, 26, 27 }, { 28, 29, 30 },
        };
        std::size_t length = write(sock, buffer(data), ec);

        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lk(mx);
        std::cout << "sent: " << length << " bytes\n";
    }

}

int main() {
    boost::thread_group tg;
    tg.create_thread(server);
    tg.create_thread(client);

    tg.join_all();
}
```

Prints

```
sent: 12 bytes
length:12 data: [1,2,3]
sent: 120 bytes
length:120 data: { [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12], [13,14,15], [16,17,18], [19,20,21], [22,23,24], [25,26,27], [28,29,30],  }
```

### For non-POD data

You can use e.g. Boost Serialization to serialize the data

Comment: What happens when you transfer the POD-type to machines with other endianess? Or between 32/64-bits? Or between different compilers which may produce different layouts? Or even between code compiled with different compiler settings?

Comment: @Jens You get implementation defined behaviour, what else? It was already addressed by others and in comments

Comment: I could read your answer in a way that I can savely transfer a POD-type over the network. I have seen this assumption in code various times, so I would like to prevent answers that do not explicitly state the restrictions of that approach.

Comment: @Jens I made the caveats more explicit now. I merely meant to zoom in on the APIs for asio buffer handling here, greatly simplifying the code from the OP's code.

Comment: Extended the POD sample to have client and server on [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd3a726367ad78a2)

Comment: Hi @sehe: Thanks for the example it works. However could you please help me to understand the mutex. What is it guarding and against what ?!

Comment: It guards `std::cout` against concurrent access... (so you get readable output)

Comment: @sehe: I have another question. Excuse me if its a very basic C++ question. Bother server and client have two blocks of code. First block sending(client)/ Accepting (server) single object of type CMYType and the second block is sending and accepting a vector of CMYType objects. How does the server knows, which block of the accept code should be executed based on the type of data sent?!

Comment: _(Please stop with the excess interpunction?! It looks like you're yelling at me?!)_ In the demo it's just the order in which things arrive, because the demo is hardcoded. Normally, you have an application protocol so you _know_ what you should expect.