# Boost async_ retrieval functions return 0 bytes

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, tcp

I am trying to setup a basic Async TCP server to accept network packets from an old Game Client (reversing the network protocol to build a private server for fun). The client connects to the server and the server sends the initializer packet back to the client (part of games protocol) properly, but when I go to queue a socket->async_read_some or socket->async_receive or boost::asio::async_read the handler will always return 0 bytes transferred with no error. My question is why?

Here are the relevant files.

TCPConnection.h

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include "Core.h"
#include "DungeonRunnersPacket.h"

class TCPConnection : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<TCPConnection> {
    private:
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket            socket;
        std::vector<uint8_t>                    packetDataBuffer;

        TCPConnection(boost::asio::io_context& boostIOContext) : socket(boostIOContext) {
            
        }

    protected:

    public:        
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& getSocket() {
            return this->socket;
        }

        void handleRead(const boost::system::error_code& errorCode, const std::size_t bytesReceived) {
            if(bytesReceived > 0) {
                std::cout << "Handle Read: " << bytesReceived << std::endl;
            } else {
                if(!errorCode) {
                    this->startRead();
                } else {
                    std::cout << "LOSER: " << errorCode.message() << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }

        void startRead() {
            this->socket.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(this->packetDataBuffer), boost::bind(&TCPConnection::handleRead, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }

        void sendPacket(DungeonRunnersPacket packet) {
            const size_t bytes = this->socket.send(boost::asio::buffer(packet.packetData));
            //std::cout << "Wrote " << bytes << std::endl;
        }

        static boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection> create(boost::asio::io_context& boostIOContext) {
            return boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection>(new TCPConnection(boostIOContext));
        }
};
```

TCPServer.h

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>

#include "Core.h"
#include "DungeonRunnersPacket.h"
#include "TCPConnection.h"

class TCPServer {
    private:

    protected:
        boost::asio::io_service                                             boostIOService;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor                                      boostSocketAcceptor;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint                                      serverEndpoint;
        bool                                                                shouldStop;
        bool                                                                started;
        unsigned short                                                      serverPort;
        std::vector<uint8_t>                                                packetDataBuffer;

        virtual void onConnection(boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection> newConnection) = 0;
        virtual void onDataReceived(boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection> newConnection, std::vector<uint8_t>& packetData) = 0;

        void handleAccept(boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection> newConnection, const boost::system::error_code& errorCode) {
            if(!errorCode) {
                this->onConnection(newConnection);
                newConnection->startRead();
            } else {
                LOG("TCPServer::handleAccept", "ERROR - " << errorCode.message());
            }

            if(!this->shouldStop && this->started) {
                startAccept(this->boostIOService, this->boostSocketAcceptor);
            }
        }

        void startAccept(boost::asio::io_service& boostIOService, boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor& boostSocketAcceptor) {
            boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection> newConnection = TCPConnection::create(boostIOService);
            boostSocketAcceptor.async_accept(newConnection->getSocket(), boost::bind(&TCPServer::handleAccept, this, newConnection, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }

    public:
        TCPServer(unsigned short port) : serverEndpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port), boostSocketAcceptor(boostIOService) {
            this->serverPort = port;
        }

        void start() {
            this->shouldStop = false;
            this->started    = true;

            this->boostSocketAcceptor.open(this->serverEndpoint.protocol());
            this->boostSocketAcceptor.bind(this->serverEndpoint);
            this->boostSocketAcceptor.listen();

            std::cout << "Server Started On Port: " << this->serverPort << std::endl;

            startAccept(this->boostIOService, this->boostSocketAcceptor);

            this->boostIOService.run();
        }

        void stop() {
            std::cout << "Stopping Server..." << std::endl;
            this->shouldStop = true;
        }
};
```

AuthServer.cpp

```
#include "Core.h"
#include "TCPServer.h"

class AuthServer : public TCPServer {
    private:

    protected:
        void AuthServer::onConnection(boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection> newConnection) {
            LOG("AuthServer::onConnection", "Sending Client Init Packet.");
            newConnection->sendPacket(AuthServerPacketClientInit());
        }

        void AuthServer::onDataReceived(boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection> newConnection, std::vector<uint8_t>& packetData) {
           
        }

    public:
        AuthServer() : TCPServer(2106) {
            
        }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {     
    AuthServer* authServer = new AuthServer();
    authServer->start();
}
```

Comment: For `boost::asio::buffer` you have to specify how many bytes you want to read. In your case - `vector` as buffer is empty, so you read 0 bytes. Resize this buffer to the size you want before reading,  or consider using `boost::asio::dynamic_buffer` - it doesn't need initial size.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [boost asio write/read vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43657070/boost-asio-write-read-vector)

Comment: That makes sense yes thank you. That being said I am now getting a new stupid error:

error C2672: 'boost::asio::buffer_sequence_begin': no matching overloaded function found

having changed boost::asio::buffer(packetDataBuffer) to boost::asio::dynamic_buffer(packetBufferData)

Comment: Further research shows that dynamic_buffer cant be used in tandem with Socket functions. After changing to boost::asio::async_read and passing the socket along with additional params it compiles. I still am getting 0 bytes transferred though...