# C++ boost asio : simple server/client with boost:asio::read and boost::asio::write passing a vector of int

Tags: c++, boost-asio

server.cpp

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <vector>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service ctx;
    std::vector<int> vc = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    tcp::acceptor s(ctx, tcp::endpoint({}, 1234));
    tcp::socket conn = s.accept();
    boost::asio::write(conn, boost::asio::buffer(vc));
}
```

client.cpp

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service ctx;
    tcp::socket s(ctx);
    s.connect(tcp::endpoint({}, 1234));
    std::vector<int> data(10);
    boost::asio::read(s, boost::asio::buffer(&data, sizeof(data)));

    for (auto x : data)
    {
        std::cout << x;
    }
}
```

What I expected: I expect server.cpp send a vector of int {} to the client

```
std::vector<int> vc = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

the client.cpp will then receive it and store it in `data` and print it out

Current outcome: It is printing random outcome and it did not end the program (infinite). Some stuff copy from the command line , but it wont stop

```
26710220016661817222889274343557-214234613021914980240162615587848787224662874348677-17396929467224662874344069-204168283435745930074342533275669381911258937235205-10518278365142660544104632-2123472756944701572-531734500513653821913629-431025833424607876961438854961439111-1605430441513807051429161632526724-514957158-1286708961-1722871465961441157961440647-10517823135587861975587910445420122923239035401615725572156135866-921828804-53346303354091785516346447661095676702-529630690162195379954202857416346304291095676702-5296301791134131916325264895177476-53175062851527985158940-514916202558825605-428968316-244381721-1052917621558784836644769668-2041704702-2039585146-244387042-1972796771370310219-227626210-1841446849-244403426-240316597-1972796411370309963-227626210-1841446813-244403426-944959413-244387041-23083408513630013831919857438-1303465186-1536266722-2276098271689063955722665261701735454-46249085116722869991632510750-4814189801664991319558789404-246504676163873306321934878-512852195-508750817540917819-4289364201756172547-164364287-173190433-491957361-18996792912092702721463582721756954624676495360-2143748096148180172812092702759437233-398605863227607747-1588838227121307139359768881-1556233763-1269955807-1049730683-445750395-398606325110167107-1488174931-95114723612151757815976888
```

I had tried to follow this [How to receive a custom data type from socket read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328264/how-to-receive-a-custom-data-type-from-socket-read/33335109#33335109) , but it does not help.

Comment: You're reading into the vector structure itself rather than the data if contains, try constructing the buffer on the client as you do in the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are messing up the buffer size while reading

```
boost::asio::read(s, boost::asio::buffer(&data, sizeof(data)));
```

is wrong, should probably be:

```
boost::asio::read(s, boost::asio::buffer(data));
```

you are passing the size of the vector object, not the size of the vector storage.

BTW with boost you should not need to set the size as it can read it from the vector itself.

NOTE: your code will still fail because you actually send 9 integer and try to receive 10, so you'll get a "end of file" exception from read, but this is another story.

Comment: This work, I tried both at first and it doesn't work, and it is because I did not count number of integer in a vector probably, just a minor careless mistake sorry. It work fine now.

But can I know how to receive vector of unknown size?

Comment: you can use another version of read that use a CompletionCondition, for example

Comment: "But can I know how to receive vector of unknown size?" - use serialization (Boost Serialization, json or whatever) and include a message framing protocol

Comment: I went ahead and showed how Boost Serialization could be used to send/receive arbitrarily complex data structures.

Answer (score 1):

> "But can I know how to receive vector of unknown size?" - use
> serialization (Boost Serialization, json or whatever) and include a
> message framing protocol –  [sehe  5 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940696/c-boost-asio-simple-server-client-with-boostasioread-and-boostasiowri/74945217#comment132250369_74940799)

Because I believe in "show, don't tell", here is an example that uses C++20 with Boost Serialization to implement a data-echo service that sends the following structure across (and back):

```
struct ApplicationData {
    std::vector<int>              ints;
    std::map<std::string, double> map;
};
```

### Serialization

For serialization, it is enough to supply:

```
    void serialize(auto& ar, unsigned) { ar & ints & map; }
```

Boost serialization knows how to deal with strings, maps and vectors.

Let's also make it easy to use Boost Serialization given `asio::streambuf` objects:

```
static constexpr auto FRAME = "FRAME_SEPARATOR"sv;
static inline auto& as_frame(auto const& data, asio::streambuf& buf) {
    std::ostream os(&buf);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive(os) << data;
    os << FRAME << std::flush;
    return buf;
}

template <typename T> static inline T from_frame(asio::streambuf& buf) {
    T obj;
    std::istream is(&buf);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(is);
    ia >> obj;
    if (std::string frame; is >> frame && frame == FRAME)
        return obj;
    throw std::runtime_error("Stream error");
}
```

#### Coroutines

Using a few handy defs we can write coroutines in a jiffy:

```
using Void     = asio::awaitable<void>;
using Acceptor = asio::use_awaitable_t<>::as_default_on_t<tcp::acceptor>;
using Socket   = asio::use_awaitable_t<>::as_default_on_t<tcp::socket>;
```

### Server

The server can be just this:

```
Void server(uint16_t port) {
    auto ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    
    for (Acceptor acc(ex, {{}, port});;)
        co_spawn(ex, echo_data(co_await acc.async_accept()), detached);
}
```

Of course, we need to implement `echo_data`:

```
Void echo_data(Socket s) {
    asio::streambuf buf;
    co_await async_read_until(s, buf, FRAME);
    auto request = from_frame<ApplicationData>(buf);

    std::cout << "server echo to " << s.remote_endpoint() << ", " << request << std::endl;
    co_await async_write(s, as_frame(request, buf));
}
```

### Client

Now it's time to code up a client:

```
Void client(uint16_t port, ApplicationData const data) {
    auto ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    Socket s(ex);
    co_await s.async_connect({{}, port});

    asio::streambuf buf, received;
    co_await async_write(s, as_frame(data, buf));
    co_await async_read_until(s, received, FRAME);
    auto response = from_frame<ApplicationData>(received);
    std::cout << "client response " << response << std::endl;
    std::cout << "client roundtrip " << std::boolalpha << (response == data) << std::endl;
}
```

> To allow for the debug output we've added `operator==` and
> `operator<<` to `ApplicationData`:
>
> ```
> bool operator==(ApplicationData const&) const = default;
> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ApplicationData const& ad) {
>     return os << fmt::format("{{ints:{} complex:{}}}", ad.ints, ad.map);
> }
> ```

### Full Demo [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b58b69954650241)

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::detached;
using asio::ip::tcp;

#include <fmt/ranges.h>
using namespace std::literals;

struct ApplicationData {
    std::vector<int>              ints;
    std::map<std::string, double> map;

    void serialize(auto& ar, unsigned) { ar & ints & map; }
    bool operator==(ApplicationData const&) const = default;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ApplicationData const& ad) {
        return os << fmt::format("{{ints:{} complex:{}}}", ad.ints, ad.map);
    }
};

static constexpr auto FRAME = "FRAME_SEPARATOR"sv;
static inline auto& as_frame(auto const& data, asio::streambuf& buf) {
    std::ostream os(&buf);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive(os) << data;
    os << FRAME << std::flush;
    return buf;
}

template <typename T> static inline T from_frame(asio::streambuf& buf) {
    T obj;
    std::istream is(&buf);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(is);
    ia >> obj;
    if (std::string frame; is >> frame && frame == FRAME)
        return obj;
    throw std::runtime_error("Stream error");
}

using Void     = asio::awaitable<void>;
using Acceptor = asio::use_awaitable_t<>::as_default_on_t<tcp::acceptor>;
using Socket   = asio::use_awaitable_t<>::as_default_on_t<tcp::socket>;

Void echo_data(Socket s) {
    asio::streambuf buf;
    co_await async_read_until(s, buf, FRAME);
    auto request = from_frame<ApplicationData>(buf);

    std::cout << "server echo to " << s.remote_endpoint() << ", " << request << std::endl;
    co_await async_write(s, as_frame(request, buf));
}

Void server(uint16_t port) {
    auto ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    
    for (Acceptor acc(ex, {{}, port});;)
        co_spawn(ex, echo_data(co_await acc.async_accept()), detached);
}

Void client(uint16_t port, ApplicationData const data) {
    auto ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    Socket s(ex);
    co_await s.async_connect({{}, port});

    asio::streambuf buf, received;
    co_await async_write(s, as_frame(data, buf));
    co_await async_read_until(s, received, FRAME);
    auto response = from_frame<ApplicationData>(received);
    std::cout << "client response " << response << std::endl;
    std::cout << "client roundtrip " << std::boolalpha << (response == data) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    co_spawn(ioc, server(2233), detached);
    co_spawn(ioc,
             client(2233, {{3, 4, 5}, {{"one third", 1. / 3}, {"one fourth", 1. / 4}}}),
             detached);
    co_spawn(ioc, client(2233, {{42}, {{"LtUaE^2", 1.764e3}}}), detached);

    ioc.run_for(3s);
}
```

When run with

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lfmt -lboost_serialization && ./a.out
```

Prints

```
server echo to 127.0.0.1:57782, {ints:[3, 4, 5] complex:{"one fourth": 0.25, "one third": 0.3333333333333333}}
server echo to 127.0.0.1:57784, {ints:[42] complex:{"LtUaE^2": 1764}}
client response {ints:[3, 4, 5] complex:{"one fourth": 0.25, "one third": 0.3333333333333333}}
client roundtrip true
client response {ints:[42] complex:{"LtUaE^2": 1764}}
client roundtrip true
```